# Unir listas sin repetir los datos

Tags: python

¿Cómo hago para unir ambas listas sin que se repitan datos en la listafinal?

Intenté los siguiente pero no me funciona:

```
def Union(lista1,lista2):
    i=0
    listafinal = 0
    union = lista1+lista2   
    while (i < len(union)):
        listafinal=union[i]
        if (i==union):     
            listafinal.append(union)
                
        i=i+1
    return listafinal
print (union(lista1,lista2))
```

lista1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lista2 = [2,4,6,8,10,12]

> Union une ambas listas

En el `if` se debe unir ambas pero sin que se repitan datos.

Comment: ¿Se vale cualquier cosa? Si es así: `listafinal = list(set(lista1 + lista2))`

Comment: no me sirve usar el metodo set

Comment: `listafinal = lista1 + [x for x in lista2 if x not in lista1]` salvo que tengas duplicados en lista1

Comment: hola @daniela actualice mi código y saque además varias cosas de mas que habían. Por ejemplo los paréntesis de if y while. Por otro lado colocas  i=i+1 que se va incrementando en while donde creo que para evitarte dolores de cabeza lo que te convenía era un for para recorrer la lista. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Dos listas con valores en algún caso repetidos
lista1=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lista2=[2,4,6,8,10,12]
```

Ahora la función debe recibir como parámetros las dos listas que pueden tener o no elementos repetidos.

Va recorriendo la "**listaUnion**" que es la que tiene los elementos de las dos listas e **incrementando** una nueva lista "**listafinal**" con los nuevos valores.

```
# Funcion para devolver un lista sin elementos repetidos
def union(li1,li2):
  listafinal = []
  listaUnion = li1+li2

  for i in listaUnion:
    if i not in listafinal:
      listafinal += [i]
  return listafinal


print("Lista unida sin repetidos: ", union(lista1,lista2))
```

Hacemos un **print**() llamando a la función **union**() pasándole las dos listas como parámetros.

La función **union(lista1,lista2)** devuelve todos los elementos sin repetir

El resultado seria el siguiente:

```
Lista unida sin repetidos:  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12]
```

Espero que sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto una solucion que no usa `set` (ya que mencionas que no te sirve usar ese método) ni comprensión de listas (el cual ya es usado por otra solución propuesta):

```
def Union(lista1,lista2):
    i=0
    listaFinal = []
    union = lista1 + lista2
    longitudUnion = len(union)
    while (i < longitudUnion):
        elementoActual = union[i]
        if (not elementoActual in listaFinal):
            listaFinal.append(elementoActual)
        i=i+1
    return listaFinal

lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
lista2 = [1, 3, 5, 6]

print (Union(lista1,lista2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo del Ejemplo anterior:

```
# Dos listas con valores en algún caso repetidos
lista1=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lista2=[2,4,6,8,10,12]
```

Creo que sería mucho más optimo hay uso de la función **set()** y seguidamente una función **list()** para de esta forma ahorrar unas cuantas líneas de Código.

De la Siguiente forma:

```
# Suma de Listas
lista=lista1+lista2
print(lista)
```

Resultado:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

En este caso Python unifica ambas lista manteniendo el orden inicial, de esa forma podemos hacer uso de la función **set()** para eliminar repetidos y organizarla.

```
# Suma de Listas
lista=set(lista)
print(lista)
```

Resultado:

```
{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12}
```

Una vez obtenida la colección de elementos no repetidos, podemos convertirlo de nuevo a una lista, haciendo uso de la función **list()**, para poder así iterar fácilmente entre los elementos.

```
# Suma de Listas
lista=list(lista)
print(lista)
```

Resultado:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12]
```

Ya para finalizar te dejo el Código resumido y optimizado al cual le puedes dar uso.

```
# Dos listas con valores en algún caso repetidos
lista1=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
lista2=[2,4,6,8,10,12]

print("Lista unida sin repetidos: ",list(set(lista1+lista2)))
```

Resultado:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12]
```